# javascript php adding timestamp to multiple cells

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, multiple-columns

I am new to php and javascript so please excuse my ignorance. I am trying to create a javascript to insert a timestamp to multiple cells. I did have a button to insert or update the mysql database to input the timestamp now(), but thats not the route I'm looking for. If someone has a better idea please let me know. Basically I would like to click on a button to insert time into the `<td><center><input id="field" type="text" name="time[]" size="11"></center></td>.`

```html
<?php
include 'config.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function getTimeStamp(id) {
 var now = new Date();
       return (now.getHours() + ':' + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes())));
}

function setTime() {
    document.getElementById('field').value = getTimeStamp();

</script>
</head>
<body >
<div>

<button type="button" onclick="setTime();">TimeStamp</button>
<table >

 <tr >
  <td >id</td>
  <td >First Name</td>
  <td >Last Name</td>
  <td >Location</td>
  <td >Remarks</td>
  <td >Timestamp</td>
  
 </tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
 print '<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'. $row[0] .'">' .$row[0]. '</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="first[]" value="'. $row[1] .'">' .$row[1]. '</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="last[]" value="'. $row[2] .'">' .$row[2]. '</td>
  <td><input  name="location[]" value="'. $row[3] .'">' .$row[3]. '</td>
  <td><center><input type="text" name="remarks[]" size="43"></center></td>
  <td><center><input id="field" type="text" name="time[]" size="11"></center></td>
 </tr>';
}
?>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to set the timestamp in all of the input fields `time[]` by clicking a button?

I couldn't fully test the function because your `getTimestamp` function calls other functions not defined here but it should work...

```
function setTime() {
    var col=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"][name="time[]"]');
    if(col){
        for( var n in col ) if(col[n].nodeType==1) col[n].value=getTimeStamp();
    }
}
```

---

Based upon your comment

If you wish to set the timestamp uniquely to each text input based upon clicking into the field then the function and assignments needs to be a little different. As you would no longer need the button with attached `setTime` function you could instead use something like this and remove the button and delete the `setTime` function...

```
function bindTimeEvents(){
    var col=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"][name="time[]"]');
    if( col ){
        for( var n in col )if( col[ n ].nodeType ==1 ){
            col[n].addEventListener('click',function(e){
                this.value=getTimeStamp();
            }.bind( col[n] ),false);
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',bindTimeEvents,false);
```

Comment: As pointed out by @Arif - the ID needs to be unique - you can simply remove it from your code if you elected to use the function above as the ID is not needed to target the elements programatically.

Comment: This worked perfect as wellt! Thank you! I didn't explain it well enough what I was tying to do. Now I'm getting the same time in all the input[type="text"][name="time[]"] . I would like, is to select the cell with my cursor and click the timestamp button and input unique time in there.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to add a **`class`** not **`id`** as id is unique & class can be duplicate so rather using `<input id="field" type="text" name="time[]" size="11">` this change to `<input id="field" class="timestamp-fields" type="text" name="time[]" size="11">` then

change **`setTime`** function

```
function setTime() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('timestamp-fields'), l = elements.length, t = getTimeStamp();
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    elements[i].value = t;
  }
}
```

> But you must remember you are using clients **`Date`** which is not
>   **`UTC/GMT 0`** so you might need to convert it to your server end using PHP.

Comment: This worked perfect! Thank you! I didn't explain well enough what I was tying to do. Now I getting the same time in all the <input id="field" class="timestamp-fields" type="text" name="time[]" size="11">.  I would like is to select the cell with my cursor and click the timestamp button and input unique time in there.